# Unity: player moves up without any such code

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm creating a movement function for my character(which I've done many times but this time it's not working correctly) and here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController controller;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float gravityScale;
    public Animator animator;

    private bool shiftPressed = false;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
            shiftPressed = true;
        else
            shiftPressed = false;

        if(shiftPressed)
        {
            moveSpeed = 20f;
        } else
        {
            moveSpeed = 10f;
        }

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && controller.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
        }

        if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", moveSpeed);
        else if (moveDirection == Vector3.zero)
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0f);
        else if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", moveSpeed);

        if(moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);

        moveDirection = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection.y =  moveDirection.y + (Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime * gravityScale);
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

As you can see that there is no function to go up in the y axis except the jump function. Mysteriously, when I press the 'S' key or 'downArrow' the player moves -z as he should but ironically he moves in +y axis as well. To ensure there is no y axis function I tried making jump function a comment but did the same way still. I thought it might be some character specific problem so I tried adding the code to a cube(thinking it to be my animation mistake) but it didn't helped at any point. I ensured the character controller is set nicely(collider and stuff); I've attached screenshots.
Please help!
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is possible that the last `moveDirection.y` assignment should be *before* you call `TransformDirection`?

Comment: or maybe should be `-` instead of `+`? (what are the values of `Physics.gravity.y` and `gravityScale`?)

Comment: That makes player rotate -90 degree on the x. Due to really flipped forces Daisy

Comment: +10 gravity scale and the default 9.8 of physics.gravity

Comment: Then you are perpetually increasing `moveDirection.y` here... Why don't you expect this to move your character up?

Comment: Rafalon that would make player move up making gravity pull him off the ground

Comment: This is exactly what it currently does (unless `Time.deltaTime` is negative, which I hardly doubt)

Comment: mjwills I found which line, it was `moveDirection = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);`but how to fix it and why was the problem caused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has already been stated by several here, but it seems you still do not understand the issue, concluding from your reactions.

This line will always make your character move up.

```
moveDirection.y =  moveDirection.y + (Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime * gravityScale);
```

You are trying to use gravity (which is a force) in conjunction with manipulating transform. In Unity, you either do one of the two, not both. This will lead to undesired and hard to fix results.

If you want to use forces in your code, then i suggest the follow:

1. Add a RigidBody to your character. Check the "use gravity" checkbox.
2. Get the RigidBody in your controller script by calling and add force to it to move it.

   ```
   var rb = getComponent<RigidBody>();
   rb.AddForce(10f);
   ```

Do note that if you add force, you can add it continuosly in the Update method, or just once by passing a second paramater "forcemode".

```
rb.AddForce(10, ForceMode.Impulse); // add instant force, using mass
// Or
rb.AddForce(10, ForceMode.VelocityChange); // add instant force, ignoring mass
// Or
rb.AddForce(10, ForceMode.Force); // add continuous force, using mass
// Or
rb.AddForce(10, ForceMode.Acceleration); // add continous force, ignoring mass
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess.. your character keeps moving up by about the current downwards slope of the camera?

As your code stands, as an example, if your Camera's is Vector3(10,0,0) and if you're trying to move Vector3(5, 0, 5), you've asked the movement vector to be transformed to world space, based off of the camera transform. So, your new movement vector will be something like Vector3(5,1,5). This should do the trick:

```
var worldDirection = Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
moveDirection =  new Vector3(
  worldDirection.x,
  moveDirection.y + (Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime * gravityScale),
  worldDirection.z );
```

Comment: In this case use "your". Good Point! What I do in this case is I take the Camera Direction, put it in a Vector3 variable, set y to 0, and normalize it. That works unless you look 90° from above.

Comment: And here I am usually the one to notice your and you're violations!  I also noticed that I haven't explained the issue quite properly, TransformDirection isn't affected by position. So the y component is coming from the fact that the camera is facing slightly downwards. So a horizontal direction fed into TransformDirection will actually result in a direction returned facing slightly upwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
moveDirection.y =  moveDirection.y + (Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime * gravityScale);
```

This line always sets "y", and is modified/set as the last function prior to the ultimate statement. It is here, you should validate and verify all factors that has influence the final calculation of "y".

You must validate that each of the variables are calculated to your expected values:

```
moveDirection.y
Physics.gravity.y
Time.deltaTime
gravityScale
```

Each will influence the final value of `moveDirection.y`. Once you have verified each individual value, the final `y` value will make sense to you. If any of these values are not what you expect, you have a bug in the calculation of that variable.

Happy hunting!